# asp processorThreadMax equivalent in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, application-pool

Is there any equivalent of processorThreadMax setting for asp in asp.net?
I have web app which works under load. I've heard that applicationPool in iis7 is limited to 25 threads. I would like to make it bigger. I am using asp.net. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

To increase the value for the Threads Per Processor Limit follow these steps:
1. Click Start, point to All Programs, click Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

1. In the Connections pane, select the web server, click to select Features View, and then double-click the ASP feature.
2. Click to expand Limits Properties under Behavior, click Threads Per Processor Limit, enter the desired value for Threads Per Processor Limit and click Apply in the Actions pane.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee377050(v=BTS.10).aspx